# Corresponding or associated? Which to use?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to write a sentence wherein the context is that there is a group 'T' which has fields T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, … T<sub>n</sub>. 
Should I write fields corresponding to 'T' or fields associated with 'T'?

What exactly is the difference between the two? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of a scientific paper, I would read '**associated with**' as meaning 'related to in some way'. '**Corresponding to**' on the other hand is more strictly defined - it implies a one-to-one relationship. x and y values on a graph would be a good example - for every value of x, there is a corresponding value y.

In your example:

> group 'T' which has fields T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, … T<sub>n</sub>.

Neither seems to be the case. I would suggest something along the lines of:

> ...group 'T' which **is comprised of** fields T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, … T<sub>n</sub>.
>
> ...group 'T' which **is composed of** fields T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, … T<sub>n</sub>.
>
> ...group 'T' which **ranges from** T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, … T<sub>n</sub>.

Comment: The fields are related to 'T'. So, can't I write fields associated with group 'T'?

Comment: I can't find anything definitive on this, but T1,T2,...Tn aren't just **related to** group T. They are the building blocks that literally make up group T. **X 'is comprised of' Y** explicitly means that X is composed or made up of Y.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

> The fields **comprising** group 'T'...

See [*comprise*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comprise):

> 1. to include; contain